# List answers before questions on user profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page

Currently, when viewing a user's profile, we list their top-voted questions before their top-voted answers. Shouldn't the answers be listed first? My impression is that answers are considered more important to the system than questions, since you get twice as much rep for an answer vote. Listing the answers first would reinforce this to the user. Also for moderator elections, when people are looking at other users' profiles, the quality of a user's answers is probably the more important thing for them to look at. For employers from SO Careers looking at user's profiles, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we're looking at multiple targets:

**1. Users looking to improve reputation**

Yes, I agree that if you're looking your profile page for feedback on improving your own reputation, placing answers first makes sense as they carry the most weight per votes.

**2. Users judging a user's dedication/usefulness to the site**

In the recent moderation elections I don't think a user's answers carried as much weight as you might expect.  Getting high quantities of up-voted answers has as much to do with how often you refresh the Unanswered Questions list as it has to do with your personal expertise and desire to help others.  I believe most users are aware of this.  Personally, I believe the combination of highest-rated Questions alongside highest-rated Answers would be the best profile view to get a quick judgement of a user for a moderator position.

**3. Employers judging a user's fit for employment**

Once an employer has a feel for the basics of what a developer knows (languages, frameworks, etc) I believe they'd be much more interested in what they don't know and what types of problems the person is trying to solve on a day to day basis.  Again here I think a combination of highest-rated Questions alongside highest-rated Answers would be most appropriate, as well as a list of the most used tags.

Comment: when you say "alongside", are you suggesting some kind of two-column approach? or just that both should be displayed? if it's the latter, i completely agree that both are important--i'm just suggesting that we swap where they are on the page

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best solution but I had in mind a quick-look style section that shows the highlights (top Q's, A's, tags, etc) of a user's profile with the existing default sections below.